# Build iOS app from command line brings errors

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a project, that builds perfectly from xCode 7, but fails from bash. I'm pretty new to command line using for this purposes, so not sure, what additional info I should provide. It just runs through tons of source files and fails in CompileC section.

It brings single message:
The following build commands failed:
CompileC *path to build*Objects-normal/armv7/PGDataManager.o *path to source* PGDataManager.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

It's something with this specific source, I suppose, but I wonder why it works perfectly from xCode? Also, I've checked this PGDataManager and everything looks fine.

If I can provide additional info - please ask me.

Comment: When you do a good build in Xcode, go to the Report Navigator window and find the line where it compiled that source file.  (Be sure "All messages" is selected.)  Click the button on the right edge of the line to expand it.  Compare the compile command issued by Xcode to the one you see at the command line.

Comment: I didn't get it. I don't have issues during compiling in xCode, only from terminal

Comment: I understand.  My comment was telling you how to see a **good** compile command so that you could compare it to one that failed.

Comment: Ok, I've checked it. Architecture was different, so I tried to specify it in xcodebuild, so command now looks like xcodebuild ARCHS='armv7 arm64 armv7s' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES -scheme Project -project Project.xcodeproj -configuration Debug now all looks the same, but I still receive error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in this after some researches. Here are my steps, if anybody approach similar issues:

- at first I disabled "Find Implicit Dependencies" in settings and tried to build it from xCode again. a lot of mistakes with headers appeared, I fixed them
- I used workspace, instead of xcodeproj
- setting ARCHS seems unnecessary